# JSON using Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

First of all, my question may have already been asked but I search on many tutorial and forums and I can't make it works because I'm french and not very good in English.

I try to read JSON with my app but It doesn't work. The only thing printed is "Foundation.JSONDecoder"

This is my SWIFT 4 code :

```
func getSpots(){
    guard let downloadURL = URL(string: "http://dronespot.fr/getSpot.php") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            print("Oops Call for Help")
            return
        }

        print("downloaded")
        do
        {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            //let rates = try decoder.decode([Artwork].self, from: data)
            print(decoder)
        } catch {
            print("Error after loading")
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Artwork.swift :

```
init?(json: [Any]) {
    // 1
    self.title = json[16] as? String ?? "No Title"
    self.locationName = json[12] as! String
    self.id = 3
    self.img = "tamere"
    // 2
    if let latitude = Double(json[18] as! String),
        let longitude = Double(json[19] as! String) {
        self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    } else {
        self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    }
}
```

Expected JSON :

http://dronespot.fr/getSpot.php
Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try uncommenting the line just before `print(decoder)`? And there's no point in printing the decoder.

Comment: _The only thing printed is "Foundation.JSONDecoder"_ Because that's the only thing you _ask_ to be printed.

Comment: I tried uncommenting : "Thread 5: Fatal error: Array<Artwork> does not conform to Decodable because Artwork does not conform to Decodable"

Comment: can u show your model and expected return json

Comment: I have done it.

Comment: Did you set  class Artwork: Codable {

Comment: Why is `Artwork init` declared as optional when you don't return `nil` under any condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to use `JSONDecoder` your approach is completely wrong (apart from the issue that you commented out the actual line to decode the JSON).

Create `Artwork` as a struct adopting `Decodable`, declare the keys in the JSON as properties and add a lazy instantiated variable to build the coordinate:

```
struct Artwork : Decodable {
    let nom : String
    let description : String
    let id: String
    let img1 : String
    let latitude : String
    let longitude : String

    // there are much more keys

    lazy var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D = {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(latitude) ?? 0.0, longitude: Double(longitude) ?? 0.0)
    }()
}
```

Now decode the array of `Artwork`

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let rates = try decoder.decode([Artwork].self, from: data)
    print(rates)
} catch {
    print("Error after loading", error)
}
```